# Can't login in tomcat manager after update

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

After a system update, I can no longer log in in tomcat. It was working before the update, but it's not working any longer. Not entirely sure what happened.

OS: Arch linux

Java version: openjdk 1.8.0_25

Current Tomcat version: 8.0.15

tomcat-users.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="manager" password="manager" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

manager/manager still gives me unauthorized. Any ideas why?

Also, is there a way to see a list of all the users loaded by the tomcat instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of possible causes for this:

- Have you restarted tomcat after editing the file?
- Are you sure that the tomcat user has sufficient permissions for the config file
- Try adding the admin-gui role for the manager user

Comment: Yes, restarted tomcat after changing server.xml and tomcat-users.xml. All the files in /etc/tomcat8 have the owner group set as tomcat8:tomcat8. Just to be sure, gave 777 permissions to all the files in those folders. As you suggested, added the admin-gui role to manager, same result.

Comment: ahhh, finally found my answer. A month before I was experimenting with a JDBC realm connected to a mysql driver. Apparently I didn't restart the server after I did that and now it's fine. Sorry for your troubles. I think your answer should cover most of the inquiries with the same problem, that's why I am considering it as the answer for my question